# JavaScript document textarea issue in Safari

Tags: javascript, parsing, safari, document

I'm new to JavaScript and have been modifying a non-secure JavaScript quiz from [JavaScriptKit](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/popquiz.htm), mainly tidying it up in JSLint and Firebug and trying to get it working on Safari (specifically for the iPad). The quiz works great in IE9, Chrome, and Firefox.

After three days and the help of a forum, the issue has been narrowed down to a JavaScript method `parse` being used as a variable! Safari JavaScript debugging returns

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable parse

and that makes sense (although why the other browsers don't seem to care is weird). The current version of this, with some alerts, is available [here](http://subquark.com/html5/quiz/popquiz.htm), with the error occurring on the `results.htm` page.

The function is below and I don't know enough to see how to fix it. I changed `parse` to `parced` and other names figuring it just needs to be a variable but this makes it fail in all browsers! I don't actually understand how the document writes the information into the text areas, just that it works in three browsers like magic! Any help would be appreciated.

```
var wrong = 0;
var e, n, results, temp, totalquestions;
for (e = 0; e &lt;= 2; e++) {
    document.result[e].value = "";
}

var results = document.cookie.split(";");
alert("var results = " + results);
for (n = 0; n &lt;= results.length - 1; n++) {
    alert("results length = " + results.length); &lt;!--last alert in Safari --&gt;
    if (results[n].charAt(1) === 'q') {
        parse = n;
        alert("parse = " + parse);
    }
}

var incorrect = results[parse].split("=");
alert("var incorrect = " + incorrect);
incorrect = incorrect[1].split("/");
alert("var incorrect after split = " + incorrect);
if (incorrect[incorrect.length - 1] === 'b') {
    incorrect = "";
}

document.result[0].value = totalquestions - incorrect.length + " out of " + totalquestions;
document.result[2].value = ((totalquestions - incorrect.length) / totalquestions * 100).toFixed() + "%";
for (temp = 0; temp &lt; incorrect.length; temp++) {
    document.result[1].value += incorrect[temp] + ", ";
    alert("the value of temp is " + temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared `parse` anywhere, which might cause random issues with certain browsers.  I'd change:

```
var e, n, results, temp, totalquestions;
```

to

```
var e, n, results, temp, totalquestions, parse;
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, I'll change its name since it's a method and also declare it as you suggested! fingers crossed and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the issue is with...

```
results[n].charAt(1)
```

position 1 is actually "=" not "q"

correct code should be...

```
if (results[n].charAt(0)=='q'){
```

I know this is an old post but I actually came across this same issue Today.